# Error starting python windows service compiled using pyinstaller

Tags: python, service, pyinstaller, pywin32

I have created python script which is a windows service. Below is the code:

**client_service.py**

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import psutil
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
import time
import json
import datetime
from random import randint
from pymongo import MongoClient
from opcua import Client


curr_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
configs_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'configs', 'app_config.json')
opc_configs_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'configs', 'opc.json')
log_file_path = os.path.join(curr_path, 'logs', 'application.log')


def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.ERROR):
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='a')
    fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    streamHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    l.setLevel(level)
    l.addHandler(fileHandler)
    l.addHandler(streamHandler)


debug_file = os.path.join(curr_path, 'logs', 'application.log')
setup_logger('debug', debug_file)
log_debug = logging.getLogger('debug')


class AppService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE"
    _svc_display_name_ = "OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE"
    _svc_description_ = "OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.isrunning = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.isrunning = False

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.isrunning = True
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED, (self._svc_name_, ''))

        log_debug.error("STARTED")
        while self.isrunning:
            log_debug.error("Running")
            time.sleep(2)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(AppService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppService)
```

To test it, I am running below command:

```
> python client_service.py install
    Installing service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE
    Service installed

> python client_service.py debug
    Debugging service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE - press Ctrl+C to stop.
    Info 0x40001002 - The OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE service has started.
    2020-09-23 21:15:46,603 STARTED
    2020-09-23 21:15:46,603 Running
    2020-09-23 21:15:48,604 Running
    2020-09-23 21:15:50,606 Running
    Stopping debug service.

> python client_service.py start
    Starting service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE

> python client_service.py remove
    Removing service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE
    Service removed
```

Everything worked fine which means script has no issues. Later I have converted the `.py` to `.exe` using `pyinstaller` :

```
pyinstaller --hiddenimport=win32timezone --onefile client_service.py
```

after this, it created `client_service.exe`. So I used below commands:

```
> client_service.exe install
    Installing service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE
    Service installed

> client_service.exe debug
    Debugging service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE - press Ctrl+C to stop.
    Info 0x40001002 - The OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE service has started.
    2020-09-23 21:23:35,149 STARTED
    2020-09-23 21:23:35,149 Running
    2020-09-23 21:23:37,150 Running
    2020-09-23 21:23:39,150 Running
    Stopping debug service.

> client_service.exe start
    Starting service OPC_CLIENT_SERVICE
    Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Here I am not able to understand why the exe is not starting. How can I debug this from here. Please anyone can tell me how to debug it. Any suggestions.? Please help. Thanks

Comment: I've worked with these a lot, and sometimes the only thing I could do is remove all the nonessential code in the service file, make sure it all works, then slowly add back chunks until it breaks, then "bisect" the chunk that broke it to see which specific line broke it... It's almost always an import but their tools for finding out which import fails are primitive and not reliable.

Comment: @JacobIRR I actually followed the approach you mentioned and finally came up with this python script. Anyways I will check the script again. But my main concern is how come its running fine in debug mode and not in start mode.

Comment: I've never used that debug option there, I've only used the debug arg when running the pyinstaller command

Comment: @JacobIRR I have resolved the issue. In my case the problem was that I was using dynamic path to configs and logs file. I made it static and it started working fine.

Comment: @SAndrew are you serious that it was dynamic paths... ? I am having a similar problem right now and if this is the case I will be very sad