# Cannot start windows services

Tags: python, pywin32

I have a python program which have to run as a windows service.
However, when I try to run the service I get the error:

```
Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

As in this question [Error starting python windows service compiled using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64031887/936269) I can both install and remove the service and it is only start which fails.

I started the service development based on this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32440/936269 to question: [How do you run a Python script as a service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404/936269)

However, even with a very dialed down service see below, I get the exact same error.

```py
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket


class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

I have the following in `requirements.txt` file:

```
pywin32==306
pyinstaller==6.2.0
```

I have tried both just running

```
python main.py install
python main.py start
```

And I have tried using pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --hiddenimport win32timezone --onefile .\main.py
```

And then:

```
main.exe install 
main.exe start
```

I am running on Windows 10 Pro and Python 3.10.4.
I do install the service under my local admin user.

I cannot see how I can make the service even simpler to test.

Comment: Is the `pass` in the main function also on you're actual script? The service might be flagged as non-responsive by windows.

Comment: yes it is. I have also tried a logging statement same issue

Comment: Totally a random stab in the dark but will `python` resolve to what you expect within a service context?  For the service “user” - not *your* user.  Path ok, for example?  PYTHONPATH?  That kinda stuff.

Comment: @JLPeyret shouldn’t it do that at least for the pyinstaller one ?

Comment: haven't been on Windows for a while.  but one thing that is going to be different with a service is that it is **not** running as your user.  so, if the code seems to match other code you use as inspiration, and you have stripped it way down, I'd start thinking about how the environment/context with a non-you user.  Like I said, stab in the dark, but in my experience one can waste a lot of time *assuming* things look the same to a different user.  i.e. I would less at your code and more at the execution context.

Comment: @JLPeyret I will look into this now. I was just assuming that at least with pyinstaller which technically should bundle python it would work.